# How to detect collision in javafx between rectangle and imageview object

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, collision, rectangles

I am trying to detect the collision between an ImageView object and a Rectangle in javafx. The code below does not work and I'm not sure why. Nothing happens when the objects overlap each other. The original file of the image is a png if that makes a difference. The imageview object is moved with arrows and the rectangle is also moving with TranslateTranslation.

```
public void collision(ImageView a, Rectangle b) {
    if (a.getBoundsInLocal().intersects(b.getBoundsInLocal())) {
        b.setY(-100);
        score++;
    }
}
```

imageview movement code:

```
    playg.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
                basket.setLayoutX(basket.getLayoutX() + 15);
                brect.setLayoutX(basket.getLayoutX() + 15);

            } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
                basket.setLayoutX(basket.getLayoutX() - 15);
                brect.setLayoutX(basket.getLayoutX() - 15);
            }
        }
    });
```

rectangle animation code:

```
    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(4), rect2);
    tt.setByY(800f);
    tt.setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);
    tt.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getBoundsInParent()` instead of `getBoundsInLocal()`.

Some quick testing showed the `BoundingBox` didn't change between two different positions when using local but did when using in-parent. I'm guessing this is due to the fact `getBoundsInParent()` uses the transforms on the node (see the Javadoc between the two for more info).

<s>However, I did not test if this effects the result of the intersecting method.</s> Edit: Decided to do more tests. Adding two `Rectangle`s to a `StackPane` and moving one around showed that "local" **always** showed true and "in-parent" only showed true when visually intersecting. This is because, as far as "local" is concerned, the rectangles never left their starting positions which means they are technically intersecting at all times. But "in-parent" showed their true positions within the `StackPane`.

Comment: Hmm... I changed one of my rectangles to an `ImageView` and it still worked for me (I even used a png file). Even looking at the new code you posted I'm not doing much different. When are you checking for collisions in you code?

Comment: Actually I found out that the function is only called once, when the window opens. The getBoundInParent() worked for that once though, thanks. Do you know how to get the program to continuously check for collision? I called the function once in the start() method

Comment: You could continuously check in a while loop in a different thread. I think I would use an `AnimationTimer` though because it is called on the FX Application Thread and is only called once per frame. The latter approach helps with threading issues (such as changing GUI state when a collision is detected).